# MongoDb select objects from an array where object property matches coondition

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm relatively new to mongoose and nodejs. And i'm trying to hackup a quick server side script in nodejs.

I'm trying to retrieve data as array of objects from mongoDb using mongoose.

Here is what my Schema looks like -

```
var heatmapSchema = new Schema({
vuid: String
coordinates: [
    {
        x: Number,
        y: Number,
        c: Number,
        timestamp: Number
    }
  ]
}, {collection: collectionName} );
```

As you can see `coordinates` is an array of objects. I want to query mongoDb so I get an array of these coordinate objects, where `c = 1` (`c` property in `coordinate` equals 1) i.e. -

```
[
   {
      x: 100,
      y: 230,
      c: 1,
      timestamp: 1233312312
   },
   {
      x: 120,
      y: 240,
      c: 1,
      t: 1233313425
   }
   ......
]
```

What would be the best way to achieve this in mongoose?

**UPDATE**

The closest I have gotten so far is using the below query -

```
heatmapModel.aggregate(
[
    {
        $unwind: '$coordinates'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'coordinates.c': 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            '_id': 0,
            'coordinates.x': 1,
            'coordinates.y': 1,
            'coordinates.c': 1,
            'coordinates.timestamp': 1
        }
    }
],
function (err, result) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    console.log(result);
    process.exit();
}
);
```

Which gives me the following output -

```
[ { coordinates: { x: 601, y: 165, c: 1, timestamp: 1438840800424 } },
  { coordinates: { x: 484, y: 192, c: 1, timestamp: 1438840801211 } },
  { coordinates: { x: 484, y: 192, c: 1, timestamp: 1438840801388 } },
  { coordinates: { x: 414, y: 394, c: 1, timestamp: 1438840802378 } },
  .....
]
```

How do I get rid of the unwanted `coordinates` key in the json?

Answer (score 1):

heatMap.find({'coordinates.c': 1}); should work.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. That was the obvious first thing i tried, but the result contains values that have `coordinates.c = 0` as well

Comment: I have updated my question. But if your question was how I executed your above mentioned query -

    heatmapModel.find({"coordinates.c": 1}).exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             process.exit(1);
        }

        console.log(data);
        process.exit();
    });